# android-cache each fragment in viewpager but doesnt load until the fragment is visible to user?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager in my app with 4 tabs. I know I can do `setOffscreenPageLimit(3)` to retain all the pages from reloads. but my problem now is that all 4 tabs need to send request to server and that take some time, especially when all 4 requests are sent at the same time. Is there a way that I can do like `setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` which makes the app only loads the current page but retain the page when swipe happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can do like setOffscreenPageLimit(0) which makes
>   the app only loads the current page but retain the page when swipe
>   happen?

No you can not, in order to have a better UX android dose not allow to set it to 0, so the default value and the lowest one is 1 which means it loads your off screen fragments of left and right of your current fragment.

what should you do?

3 different solutions I can offer you:

1) Send your request to server at the function `onPageSelected(int position)`

2) if you are using `actionBar` tab use `onTabSelected` and send your request to server.

3) send your request at the `onResume` of your fragment by using `setUserVisibleHint` and `getUserVisibleHint` function to determine when your fragment is really visible to your user so send it at the right time.

Comment: thanks for the tips! I tried your third solution. but instead of sending request within `onResume`, I did it in `setUserVisiblieHint`. I check if the request has not previously sent and `isVisibleToUser == true` then send the request. works as expected!